# R shiny D3 network graph with NodeSize

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny

I am using D3Network library for plotting graph on web (using shiny).

```
wc <- cluster_walktrap(finalGraph)
members <- membership(wc)
karate_d3 <- igraph_to_networkD3(finalGraph, group = members)

forceNetwork(Links = karate_d3$links, Nodes = karate_d3$nodes, 
                     Source = 'source', Target = 'target', opacity = 0.85, zoom = TRUE,
                     NodeID = 'name', Group = 'group', fontSize = 20, Nodesize = "weight",
                     colourScale = JS('force.alpha(1); force.restart(); d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);'))
```

finalGraph here is a weighted igraph which I convert to d3

```
V(finalGraph)$weight <- #logic to assign weight
```

I want the Nodesize of D3 to represent the weight value but doing `Nodesize = "weight"` does not work as column is not defined. How do I add this as attribute/column for d3 so it can plot the weight?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? e.g. `dput(finalGraph)`.

Comment: finalGraph is an igraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the size in the node matrix. Here is a fully working example including a graph. Please note, that the node size is not directly taken but somehow recalculated by another function (radiusCalculation).

```
library(networkD3)
library(igraph)

# build graph
finalGraph <- erdos.renyi.game(10,0.3)
wc <- cluster_walktrap(finalGraph)
members <- membership(wc)
karate_d3 <- igraph_to_networkD3(finalGraph, group = members)

# here is the important line: set size!
karate_d3$nodes$size = abs(rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=10))^2

forceNetwork(Links = karate_d3$links, Nodes = karate_d3$nodes, 
             Source = 'source', Target = 'target', opacity = 0.85, zoom = TRUE,
             NodeID = 'name', Group = 'group', fontSize = 20, Nodesize = 'size',
             colourScale = JS('force.alpha(1); force.restart(); d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);'))
```